# How to fix error NSPOSIXErrorDomain:28 on Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, error

Sometimes when I want to browse on Safari, I receive the following error: `(NSPOSIXErrorDomain:28)` on my tabs. Is there anyone who knows why this error occur and how to avoid them?

I use macOS Monterey version 12.3.1

Comment: Which urls show this?

Comment: @mmmmmm, many urls. There is not a specific url which gives this error.

Comment: OSXDaily has this - https://osxdaily.com/2022/01/28/fix-safari-cant-open-page-nsposixerrordomain28-error-on-mac/ - idk how helpful it might be, can't test.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thank you! It is fixed by updating my `macOS` to version 12.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved for me when I updated my macOS Monterey version from 12.3.1 to 12.4.